# Solving the following Initial Value Problem

Tags: derivatives, initial-value-problems

Solve the initial value problem:
$$y_1'=2y_1+2e^{2t}$$
$$y_2'=3y_1+2y_2+3e^{2t}$$
and $y_1(0)=2, y_2(0)=3$

I'm trying to start by using $y'=Ay+g$

Does $g=\begin{bmatrix}2e^{2t}\\3e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}$

Following, I get $det(A-\lambda I)$ as $\lambda^{2}-4\lambda+4=0$

How can I obtain the homogeneous solution by this equation?

Comment: yes $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: @Surb Following, how could I obtain the homogeneous solution with the calculated equation?

Comment: @Moo You mean to integrate first the equation $y_1'$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

I denote $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 3&2\end{pmatrix},$$
and $g$ as you did. Let $y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}.$ Unfortunately, $A$ is not diagonalizable. Nevertheless :
\begin{align*}
y'=Ay+g&\iff e^{-At}y'-e^{-At}Ay=e^{-At}g\\
&\iff \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t}\left(e^{-At}y\right)=e^{-At}g,
\end{align*}
where $e^{A}$ is the exponential matrix of $A$. I let you conclude.

Comment: To follow your calculations, would this be the homogeneous solution?

Comment: No, this will be the general solution.

Comment: Is the next step, finding out the general solutions for $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: Yes of course ! You just have to integrate in bother side, and you'll immediately get the solution...

Comment: By bother side you mean on $y_1'$ and $y_2'$?

Comment: No. If $y'(x)=g(x)$, then $\int_0^x y'(t)dt=\int_0^x g(t)dt$.

Comment: Is it right that, now I integrate the equations of $y_1'$ and $y_2'$ and introduce $x$ and $0$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I really don't see the difficulty here.